# JMeter - Accurate in calculating Load time?

Tags: jmeter

Is JMeter accurate in calculating Load time of main request? I see that it's not. With 6 parallel connections it's not accurately adding the Load time for main request. I am not taking about 10 to 50 miliseconds, I have seen that it's adding the response times of two embedded resources which are together in 6 parallel connections!!! ..any idea??

Answer (score 0):

If "you see that it's not" - then you should raise the issue in [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html), be ready to present all the necessary stuff in order to reproduce the issue, i.e. your test plan or [network dumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) from JMeter and from the real browser showing the difference.

Given you [properly configure JMeter in order to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) you should see the same or at least similar response times, make sure to [clear the browsing history](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic) before measuring as browsers tend to [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) content in general and embedded resources in particular

Be aware of one [major limitation](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

so if any of these "embedded resources" calls are driven by JavaScript - JMeter won't execute them automatically